# Facebook pass incorrect data to database

Tags: python, database, postgresql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm Need help building an application which let me store facebook public data in the database using python3, turnout all the data that came from Facebook got turned into weird string
[image: Weird String] instead of the value showing in the python output
[image]

My code

```
host = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0"
path = "/me"
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
"access_token": ACCESS_TOKEN
})

url = "{host}{path}?{params}".format(host = host, path = path, params = 
params)
print(url)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

print(resp)

    params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
"fields": 'name',
"access_token": ACCESS_TOKEN
})
url = "{host}{path}?{params}".format(host = host, path = path, params = 
params)
uName = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
pprint.pprint(uName)


params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
"fields": 'id',
"access_token": ACCESS_TOKEN
})
url = "{host}{path}?{params}".format(host = host, path = path, params = 
params)
uId = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
pprint.pprint(uId)


cur.execute(""
"
insert into COMPANY(ID, NAME, AGE, ADDRESS, SALARY, STRING) VALUES( % s, % 
s, % s, % s, % s, % s)
""
", (temp_id,uName,age,address,salary,uId,))
conn.commit() conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice in your python output, uName is actually binary data (`b'stuff'` means binary), and is actually JSON.

You need to decode it to get a text

```
uName = uName.decode('utf-8')
```

And then, if you need, [decode the json](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.loads).